# Writing Bits to a file using BitSet & FileOutputStream

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream, bitset

I've run into a bit of a problem when it comes to writing specific bits to a file. I apologise if this is a duplicate of anything but I could not find a reasonable answer with the searches I ran.

I have a number of difficulties with the following:

1. Writing a header (Long) bit by bit (converted to a byte array so the
   FileOutputStream can utilise it) to the file.
2. Writing single bits to the file. For example, at one stage I am required to write a single bit set to 0 to the file so my initial thought would be to use a BitSet but Java seems to treat this as a null?

   ```
   BitSet initialPadding = new BitSet();
   initialPadding.set(0, false);
   fileOutputStream.write(initialPadding.toByteArray());
   ```

---

1)

I create a FileOutputStream as shown below with the necessary file name:

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

I am attempting to create an ".amr" file so the first step before I perform any bit manipulation is to write a header to the beginning of the file. This has the following value:

```
Long defaultHeader = 0x2321414d520aL;
```

I've tried writing this to the file using the following method but I am pretty sure it does not write the correct result:

```
fileOutputStream.write(defaultHeader.byteValue());
```

Am I using the correct streams? Are my convertions completely wrong?

---

2)

I have a `public BitSet fileBitSet;`which has bits read in from a ".raw" file as the input. I need to be able to extract certain bits from the BitSet in order to write them to the file later. I do this using the following method:

```
public int getOctetPayloadHeader(int startPoint) {

    int readLength = 0;

    octetCMR = fileBitSet.get(0, 3);
    octetRES = fileBitSet.get(4, 7);

    if (octetRES.get(0, 3).isEmpty()) {

        /* Keep constructing the payload header. */

        octetFBit    = fileBitSet.get(8, 8);
        octetMode    = fileBitSet.get(9, 12);
        octetQuality = fileBitSet.get(13, 13);
        octetPadding = fileBitSet.get(14, 15);
        ... }
```

What would be the best way to go for writing these bits to a file bearing in mind that I may be required to sometimes write a single bit or 81 bits at a particular offset in the `fileBitSet` ?

Comment: Question 2 (the first one) you're writting the value 0 to a file, this is the null character according to most charsets so it won't show up in most text editors.  At a higher level, why are you working with bits?  Working with bytes is going to be much easier.

Comment: `BitSet` is conceptually supposed to be infinitely long and have infinitely many `false` bits, so setting one bit to `false` should actually have no effect on it.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I'll try to align the bits onto byte boundaries and writing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one thing you can write to an OutputStream: bytes. You have to do the composing of your bits into bytes yourself; only you know the rules how the bits are to be put together into bytes.

As for stuff like:

```
Long defaultHeader = 0x2321414d520aL;
fileOutputStream.write(defaultHeader.byteValue());
```

You should take a close look at the *javadocs* for the methods you are using. `byteValue()` returns a single byte; so *of course* its not doing what you expect. Working with streams is well explained in oracles tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html

For writing single bits or groups of bits, you will need a custom OutputStream that handles grouping the bits into bytes to be written. Thats commonly called a *BitStream* (there is no such class in the JDK); you have to either write it yourself (which I highly recommend, its a very good excercise to teach you about bits and bytes) or find one on the web.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am still unsure of how to work with bits effectively but this notifies me that I will need to write my own BitStream class if I want to work with bits.

Comment: @GeorgeTretyakov There's nothing wrong with utilizing BitSet for composing bits in memory, but only you can define the semantics for mapping it to a stream; there is no unique naturall mapping from BitSet to bytes. Randomly chosing existing JDK classes whos name suggests they do something related without carefully checking their semantincs is doomed to fail; its a common beginners mistake to assume that class, method or variable names imply anything about their semantics (and that the assumed semantics coincide with their intent). There is no way around checking out the documentation